# Reactjs function invoking on page load before onClick event

Tags: reactjs, function, onclick

Function working while the page load my code as follow
**Parent**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ExtnButton from "./Button";
class MovieList extends Component {
  handleDelete = index => {
    console.log("inside handleDelete:");
  };
 render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
     <ExtnButton handleDelete={this.handleDelete} index={index} />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
export default MovieList;
```

**Child**

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Button extends Component {
  state = {};
  render() {
    return (
      <button
        onClick={this.props.handleDelete(this.props.index)}
        className="btn btn-danger"
      >
        Delete
      </button>
    );
  }
}
 export default Button;
```

But on page loading the function handleDelete invoking without any click event

Comment: Should be onClick={ () => this.props.handleDelete(this.props.index)}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you're calling the method inside the onClick event directly. There are three approaches to bind the events with the parameters:

Using inline arrow function:

```
onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(this.props.index)}
```

Using public class method (as you also have currently), but just need to curry:

```
handleDelete = index => () => {
  console.log("inside handleDelete:");
};
```

Using bound method:

```
handleDelete(index) {...}
```

But for this, you need to bind the `this` inside the constructor.

```
this.handleDelete = this.handleDelete.bind(this)
```

---

If you need to pass the event:

```
(using inline arrow function)
onClick={(e) => this.props.handleDelete(this.props.index, e)}
(using public class method)
handleDelete = index => e => {
  console.log(e);
};
```

---

Notice that if you use inline arrow function, then you don't need to curry the function. This will be just fine:

```
handleDelete = index => {...}
```

Or, without using public class method (ie. bound method):

```
handleDelete(index) {...}
```

Answer (score 3):

Wrong:

```js
onClick={this.props.handleDelete(this.props.index)}
```

---

Correct:

```js
onClick={() => this.props.handleDelete(this.props.index)}
```