# return _.map(this.state.categoria, categoria => { function() } is not returning

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Im having a problem to the object of a function using .map(), if I use the code it works, but if I put in a function isnot working. Exemple:

```
if(this.state.cat){ 
   return _.map(this.state.cat, categoria => {

        if(this.state.search_receive){
          somecode...

        }else {
          this.retornaItens(categoria);
          //if I put the <p>code here</p> it works
        }

    });


    retornaItens = (categoria) =>{
     return (  <p>code..</p> ); }
```

Comment: What does "is not working" mean?

Comment: is not returning if I use the code inside of the function, but if I use the code(example <p>code</p>) direct it works..

Comment: I found the problem, where I was calling the function I needed to return like: return this.retornaItens(categoria);

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the method like this:

```
retornaItens = (categoria) => () => {
```

For more info, see my another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52370100/reactjs-function-invoking-on-page-load-before-onclick-event/52370317#52370317)